# Изменяется cs при переходе на метку

Tags: ассемблер

Что происходит в 97-й строке `jmp dword ptr cs:[Off_move]`? Почему значение регистра кода заменяется адресом 7-й видеостраницы? Ведь мы делаем переход внутри программы, которая выполняется сейчас. Какая разница, что ее копия хранится где-то там еще? В переменной Off_move хранится адрес на момент загрузки программы в память до ее выполнения, и поэтому странно, что `cs` изменяется.

```
.286    ;Будем использовать инструкции 80286 процессора

cseg SEGMENT
assume cs:CSEG, ds:CSEG, es:CSEG, ss:CSEG
org 100h

Begin:
    jmp Init        ;Преходим на процедуру инициализации


; --- Общие данные ---
Off_move dw offset Lab_jmp  ;Смещение и
Seg_move dw 0BF00h          ;сегмент адреса, куда будем прыгать
                            ;0BF00h - адрес (сегмент) 7 страницы дисплея
                            ;Младшее слово в начале, а старшее - в конце

Off_return dw offset Lab_return     ;Смещение и
Seg_return dw ?                     ;сегмент адреса для возврата


;       === Процедуры работы с файлами ===

; --- Открытие файла для записи ---
; Вход:  DX - путь файлу ASCIIZ
; Выход: Handle, BX - номер файла
Open_file proc
    mov ax,3D02h    ;Открываем файл для чтения/записи
    int 21h
    mov Handle,ax   ;Сохраняем номер файла
    mov bx,ax
    ret

Handle dw 0FFFFh ;Переменная для хранения номера файла (по умолчанию 0FFFFh)
Open_file endp

; --- Закрытие файла ---
; Вход:  Handle - номер открытого файла
; Выход: ничего
Close_file proc
    cmp Handle,0FFFFh   ;Нет открытых файлов?
    je No_close ;Тогда выходим (закрывать нечего!)

    mov bx,Handle   ;Закрываем файл...
    mov ah,3Eh
    int 21h

No_close:
   ret
Close_file endp

; --- Поиск первого файла ---
Find_first proc
        mov ah,4Eh              ;Ищем первый файл по маске (Mask_file)
        xor cx,cx               ;Атрибуты обычные (CX=0)
        mov dx,offset Mask_file ;Адрес маски в DS:DX
        int 21h                 ;Теперь (если нашли файл *.com в текущем каталоге)
                                ;имя файла находится по адресу 0BF00:001Eh,
                                ;т.е. по смещению 30...
    ret
Mask_file db '*.com',0  ;Маска для поиска (только COM-файлы)
Find_first endp

; --- Поиск следующих файлов ---
Find_next proc
      xor dx,dx     ;DS:DX указывают на DTA
      xor cx,cx
      mov ah,4Fh
      int 21h
   ret
Find_next endp

; --- Заражение файла ---
Infect_file proc
        clc     ;Пока просто сбросим флаг переноса.
                ;Типа, заразили файл успешно!
                ;Потом добавим все, что нужно...
   ret
Infect_file endp


; Процедура инициализации вируса
Init:
       mov es,Seg_move  ;ES - сегмент, куда будем перемещать код вируса,
       mov di,100h  ;DI - смещение
       mov cx,offset Finish-100h    ;CX - количество перемещаемых байт
                    ;CX = конец нашего вируса - 100h (PSP)
                    ;Т.е. CX = длина нашего вируса в байтах
       mov si,100h          ;DS:SI откуда перемещать будем
       rep movsb            ;перебрасываем нашу программу в область
                            ;7 видеостраницы

;   ___________________________________________________

;   !!! Теперь ВНИМАТЕЛЬНО следим за CS в отладчике !!!
;   ___________________________________________________

       jmp dword ptr cs:[Off_move] ;Прыгаем куда переместили (фактически на
                   ;следующую строку, только уже в сегменте
                   ;0BF00h!)


; Теперь мы уже в области экрана
Lab_jmp:
    ;Вот сюда-то мы и прыгнули с предыдущей строки! Толко CS теперь
    ;равен 0BF00h. Внимательно проследите в отладчике за этим...

       nop  ;Это для отладчика (на всякий случай!)
       nop

       push cs  ;Настроим сегментные регистры
       pop ds

       mov Seg_return,ss    ;Запомним сегмент для возврата.
                ;SS-то остается прежним!

       mov ah,1Ah   ;Установим DTA для поиска файлов
       xor dx,dx    ;Он устанавливается на тот адрес, который содержится
       int 21h      ;в регистрах DS:DX. В отладчике посмотрите,
            ;что находится в памяти на которую указывают данные
            ;регистры, т.е. DS:DX...
            ;После выполнения следующей процедуры там будет
            ;находиться что-то ОЧЕНЬ интересное...

       call Find_first  ;Ищем первый файл
       jc Nomore_files  ;Нет COM-файлов - на выход 

Inf_file:
       call Infect_file ;Нашли - пробуем заразить
       jnc Nomore_files ;Удалось заразить - выходим 

       call Find_next   ;Не удалось заразить - ищем следующий
       jnc Inf_file ;Нашли еще один COM-файл; пробуем заразить... 

Nomore_files:
       jmp dword ptr cs:[Off_return]    ;Возвращаемся в сегмент программы...
        ;Интересно, а что отладчик говорит по поводу этого jmp'а?
        ;Возможно, сегментные регистры помогут?


;Теперь мы уже в сегменте зараженной программы...
;Только что произошло самое важное!
Lab_return:
       push cs      ;Восстановим сегментные регистры...
       push cs
       pop ds
       pop es

       mov ah,1Ah   ;Восстановим DTA
       mov dx,80h
       int 21h

       ret      ;Выходим в DOS...

Finish equ $        ;Метка конца программы-вируса

CSEG ends
end Begin
```

Comment: Ну так смотрите на предыдущий код, там как раз копирование кода в видеопамять. А потом переход на скопированный код. Вы читаете код для модели памяти DOS, там указатели указывают не в виртуальное пространство, выделенное данному процессу, а на реальную память (real mode всё-таки).

Comment: Я знаю, что адреса реальные. Мне непонятно, почему происходит переход именно на скопированный код. Что изменилось при его копировании? Основные регистры cs:ip до выполнения jmp ведь указывают на "правильную" память, а не в видеосегмент. Та метка изначально указывает на место, куда программа загрузилась при запуске. Как она может поменяться при копировании?

Comment: Ну там же косвенный переход. Берём двойное слово по адресу `cs:[Off_move]` (это данные, объявленные как `Off_move dw offset Lab_jmp // Seg_move dw 0BF00h`) и прыгаем туда. То есть это всё равно что `mov cs, 0BF00h // mov ip, offset Lab_jmp`, но «за один ход».

Comment: У меня структура этой программы еще не отложилась в памяти, и я в ей плохо ориентируюсь. Но ведь у нас под меткой Lab_jmp два экземпляра кода: исходный и скопированный в видеосегмент. Почему происходит прыжок именно в скопированный? Точнее, метка одна, и за ней зафиксирован постоянный адрес. Но понятно, что я имел в виду.

Comment: Кажется, я начинаю понимать. Off_move и Seg_mov расположены рядом. Мы делаем прыжок dword ptr, то есть на этот объединенный адрес сегмент+смещение. Я прав? Здесь все дело в этом dword ptr.

Comment: Угу, так и есть: `dword ptr` делает `jmp far`, а не `jmp near`. То есть, прыжок со сменой сегмента.

Comment: Ого, как тонко придумано.

Comment: Программирование на ассемблере под DOS полностью состояло из таких трюков. То ли ещё вы увидите :)